# Python Azure Databricks initialise widget within the notebook

Tags: widget, databricks, azure-databricks

I am trying to create a widget in the middle of a notebook (and not pinned on the top).
Is anybody aware if this is possible?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For that you may try to use [ipywidgets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/notebooks/ipywidgets) instead of Databricks widgets. Ipywidgets are officially supported since version 11.0 ([announcement blog](https://www.databricks.com/blog/2022/08/09/databricks-and-jupyter-announcing-ipywidgets-in-the-databricks-notebook.html)).

The ipywidgets will be rendered in the cell where they are declared, but check the [list of existing limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/notebooks/ipywidgets#limitations).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I've already tried the approach you proposed. Unfortunately, ipywidgets are not integrated into scheduled Databricks jobs or Databricks dashboards.

Comment: if you want to use them to pass jobs parameters, then only databricks widgets are supported for that